# Angular HTML binding with JS

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular4 and I am trying to develop an app. Now I encounter with some problems and hope you can help me.

As we know, Angular use Typescript instead of JS. But it seems is's a little hard for me to change my previous HTML code with JS and all kinds of imports into the Angular style. So I hope I can simply import my old xxx.html into my Angular project.

Now I have known that I can use the following codes:

```
<div [innerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>
```

However,it tends out that I can only import the HTML codes between the div. And if there are JS codes, it will not work and will only show the text.

So I wonder if there is a way that I can simply use the HTML code with JS and all kinds of libraries imported? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't thing that a good idea with [innerHTML]. I wondering the best way to use old HTML with new angular is to copy your html files and rewrite the binding.

Comment: Why do you use angular if you don't use it? What you are trying to do opens the door for so many bugs

Comment: simply print like this <div>{{theHtmlString}}</div>.
Note the theHtmlString is an variable with value.

Example:-public theHtmlString="Hello World!"

{{  }} this curly braces generally said to be interpolation